# How to enable debug on my JUnit through Gradle test task

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, gradle

I get into trouble while I try to run my JUnit test through Gradle test task. While I run the test in eclipse directly with Run As -> JUnit test, everything is ok, the test succeeds. But through test task, test always fails. Probably some trouble with the encoding of my resource txt file. So I would like to enable debug while I am launching the test with Gradle

in build.gradle, my test task now looks like:

```
test {
    tasks.withType(Compile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

So what should I do to enable debug? I run Gradle tasks from Gradle panel in Eclipse, not from the console. Thanks!

Comment: This configuration doesn't affect the `test` task but all `Compile` tasks. Hence it shouldn't be nested inside `test { .. }`.

Comment: In some test classes (and also in regular java classes), there are some constant strings with diacritics, so I need to run test with UTF-8 encoding. While I used this, tests who failed before now runs ok. If you say this is not ok, could you help me how to correct this (While i keep diacritics string in java classes)? Use this encoding only on tests?

Comment: If you want to set the encoding for all `JavaCompile` tasks, use `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = 'UTF-8' }`. If you only want to set it for test compilation, use `compileTestJava { options.encoding = 'UTF-8' }`. (`Compile` has been deprecated and is now called `JavaCompile`.)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

To debug tests the following argument should be used: `--debug-jvm`

For example: `gradle test --debug-jvm`

Gradle will suspend execution right before running tests and wait for debugger connection on port 5005.

For executing only specific tests see [Simple name pattern](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#simple_name_pattern)

For additional options see [Debugging when running tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:debugging_java_tests).

Comment: Firstly, that's usually called an "option", not an "attribute". Secondly, it doesn't work for me to just prepend it to the command line arguments - it's necessary to append it.

Comment: This did not work for me at all...  I am able to connect with a debugger in deamon mode but none of my breakpoints compile/trigger in eclipse... this feature is kind of weak sauce

Comment: @Nik, the reason it's not working is that Eclipse does it's own build in the `bin/` folder, which is where it attaches the breakpoints. Gradle also builds to `build/classes/`, which is the classfiles it runs. Thus not working.

Comment: If you have difficulty with build-tool options, you can capture & reproduce the process launch and configure that to attach your debugger. http://literatejava.com/engineering/how-to-debug-tests-run-externally/

Comment: This doesn't work when using org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin, in which case the second part of that answer should be used : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210920/2873507

Comment: Newer versions of Gradle have a specific DSL, independent of test framework, documented in the [current Gradle version user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:debugging_java_tests)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, GRADLE_OPTS="...jdwp..." is not the same thing as `--debug-jvm` (I think). The former debugs the builder. The latter debugs the test itself.  If you run `jps` you'll see separate VMs for `GradleDaemon`, `GradleWorkerMain`, `GradleMain`

Answer (score 28):

As explained under `23.12. Test` in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/1.11/userguide/userguide_single.html), executing `gradle test -Dtest.single=MyTestClass -Dtest.debug` will suspend the test JVM upon start, and allows to connect an external debugger (such as the Eclipse debugger) on port 5005.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to use it directly from Eclipse?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by that. From what I remember, the Eclipse Gradle tooling does support custom command line parameters, so it should be possible to start the build from Eclipse. Then you'll have to fire up the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  In case where I am unable to use port 5005, how do I disable fork of test JVM. Or change the port number to something else other than 5005?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all for me using using Gradle 4.4.1, it doesn't seem to notice it at all

Comment: This doesn't work when using org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin, in which case the second part of that answer should be used : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210920/2873507

Answer (score 11):

Putting this here as `--debug-jvm` did not work for me, I was able to do this by setting:

```
 org.gradle.daemon=true
 org.gradle.jvmargs=... -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=10999
```

in

```
 ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

But when I connect with eclipse debugger for the project none of the breakpoints I've set compile/trigger... I am connected via the debugger, I can see action in the Debug view, whenever I run `gradle test` from command line, like new threads starting/stopping, but can't get breakpoints to trigger, trying to resolve this now...

Fyi to stop deamon run `gradle --stop`

### Other solution

Leaving above as reference, this worked for triggering break points in tests, I turned off deamon as I could not get it to work properly:

Using directions from this article: http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/gradle-tip-attaching-a-debugger.html

```
test {        
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug',
            '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=10999'
    }
}
```

Executed via `gradle test -DDEBUG=true`

### Solution when using the JUnit Platform Gradle plugin

The solution above won't work when using `org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin`.

Instead it should be replaced by:

```
junitPlatformTest {        
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug',
            '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=10999'
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you enabled daemon, there are two JVMs running. You are connecting to the wrong one.

Comment: 2 jvms listening on 1 port? How can that be? I don't think I was connecting to wrong jvm, deamon was registering all calls to gradle, from eclipse or command line client... Like I said I saw it "doing stuff" in debugger whenever I ran any gradle command

Answer (score 8):

I'm on 4.6 (gradle) and I'm able to debug my tests when I have this in my build.gradle file:

```
test {
    debug true
}
```

Link - https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_test

Comment: This will listen on port 5005. You can then `jdb -sourcepath <...> -attach 5005` and `stop at com.<...>.<TestClass>:<line number>`. `test {debug true}` is top level in build.gradle.