# Debug gradle test from within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, debugging, gradle

Is it possible to debug a gradle test started with

```
gradle test
```

on CLI from within eclipse? Can I add the JVM args like

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 ....
```

for remote debugging as I would do it for a normal Java program?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to run the Gradle task itself in Debug mode so that this remote port bull isn't necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gradle option is `-Dtest.debug`. Then you can connect via eclipse on port 5005.

Comment: This doesn't work when using org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin, in which case the second part of that answer should be used : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210920/2873507

Answer (score 9):

### Solution:

I prefer `gradle test --debug-jvm`. This starts the application in remote debug mode, and you can attach with any remote debugger, e.g., Eclipse, on port `5005`.
This does not only work for JUnit tests, but also for normal program executions, i.e., `gradle run --debug-jvm`.

---

### Debugger Example - Eclipse:

In Eclipse, go on your Project -> Debug as... -> Debug Configuration -> Remote Java Application. As host set `localhost`, as port `5005`.

Then you should be able to debug your tests.

---

### Additional Info:

For more information [see the official Gradle Java plugin doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test) regarding testing.

> [...] can also be enabled at invocation time via the --debug-jvm task option (since Gradle 1.12).

Comment: This doesn't work when using org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin, in which case the second part of that answer should be used : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210920/2873507

Comment: Is it possible to debug on the class files generated by `gradle` ? Since the code generated by gradle seems to be different from the one which is visible from eclipse (for auto generated implementation classes)

Answer (score 1):

Is it just a JUnit class you want to debug?  If so, just debug the JUnit class directly in Eclipse, with "Debug As".

Comment: Unfortunately the test behaves differently if started within eclipse.