# Debugger, @SpringBootTest, and Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, automated-tests

I'm new to Spring Boot and Gradle and cannot figure out how to suspend JUnit tests and connect to them with a debugger.

I invoke the automated tests on the command line `gradlew build`. What I'd like is so the execution to pause wen it reaches the test task and wait for a debugger to connect.

The JUnit test classes are annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

I have tried adding the JVM arguments for debugging to the gradle.properties file and I still can't get it to suspend, much less listen on a port for the debugger. I'm not sure what information to provide you -- ask me in the comments for files, code, or settings.

- Gradle 5.5
- Spring Boot 2.16
- Java 11

Comment: Hi ahoffer, why not running the test in debug mode inside the IDE? Do you have a special requirement for been through the terminal with gradlew build?

Comment: All the tests pass when I run them with IntelliJ. Six of the tests fail when I run them from the command line. I don't know why there is a Tomcat exception when run from the command line.  I thought I might be able to debug into it and figure out why.

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760752/how-to-enable-debug-on-my-junit-through-gradle-test-task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Omid. Thank you for the link. The solution was simple.

UPDATE: Do not use `gradlew build`. Use the `test` task instead.

`gradlew test --debug-jvm`

In the Gradle 5.5.1 docs:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:debugging_java_tests